# Add the total amount and add it to a new tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the input

```
    <Invoice>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>1</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>1</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>1110</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>1</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>2</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>1110</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>2</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>1</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>2220</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>2</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>2</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>2220</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
   </Invoice>
```

I want the ouput of the format:

```
    <Invoice>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>1</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>1</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>1110</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>1</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>2</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>1110</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>1</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>3</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>22220</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>2</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>1</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>2220</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>2</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>2</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>2220</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    <Invoice_Details>
    <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>2</Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
    <Line>3</Line>
    <Gross_Invoice_Amount>4440</Gross_Invoice_Amount>
    </Invoice_Details>
    </Invoice>
```

The values of the invoice ID and the line value are to be created as a  new  elements that add the gross of all the same ids.

Condition:
The  value of gross is required only when there is atleast one value of gross in any of the available ids.if no gross is avilable then it is not required.

Comment: please add either xslt-1.0 tag or xslt-2.0 and be specific about the xslt version you are using.

Comment: Soa accepts both the versions..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="invoices" match="Invoice/Invoice_Details" use="Consolidated_Invoice_ID"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <Invoice>
        <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/Invoice_Details[count(.|key('invoices',Consolidated_Invoice_ID)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:variable name="details" select="key('invoices',Consolidated_Invoice_ID)"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$details"/>
            <!--Add a new record with gross amount and total-->
            <Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="Consolidated_Invoice_ID"/>
            </Consolidated_Invoice_ID>
            <Line>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($details)+1"/>
            </Line>
            <Gross_Invoice_Amount>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($details/Gross_Invoice_Amount)"/>
            </Gross_Invoice_Amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```